# How to use amodem package

Tags: python, audio, file-transfer, data-transfer, modem

I am going to use the [amodem](https://github.com/romanz/amodem) package which is for data transfer through modulation on the audio signal and through the sound card. But I have little experience in the field of Python, and I didn't find any special training related to this package. I plan to use this package in a larger project . Please explain me with a simple example.
https://github.com/romanz/amodem
During testing, I use [Voicemeeter](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/) software to simulate the connection of two systems in one system. This software can return the output of my speaker virtually to the input of the microphone

I tried to use this package in my program, but I don't understand its logic

Comment: You need to ask specific questions about the problems you're having, SO is not a tutoring service.